# What's the meaning of "around" in "it's not so easy the first time around"?

Tags: meaning

If possible, I'd be very appreciated it if you find and show me which entry that 'around' equals in any dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Around" is used here as in a trip *around* loop. In a repeated process, each iteration can be considered "going around".

For example, "The first time I baked a potato, it exploded. The second time around, I poked holes in it with a fork before putting it in the microwave."